# C# Bonjour SDK RegisterRecord or AddRecord

Tags: c#, bonjour

I am building a .NET application that requires to do register itself on a Wifi network and also check for updates. I am using Apple Bonjour SDK for C# for registering a service and also browsing other services in the network. I also need to register a TXTrecord and update it periodically.
I am getting an AccessViolation error from the dnssdX.dll (Bonjour COM wrapper) when I try to use the APIs RegisterRecord or AddRecord. 
Can anyone please help with a sample on how to use the AddRecord/ RegisterRecord correctly.